# time data not matching format

Tags: python, pandas

```
time data '07/10/2019:08:00:00 PM' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f'
```

I am not sure what is wrong. Here is the code that I have been using:

```
import datetime as dt
df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%m/%d/%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

Here's a sample of the column:

```
Transaction_date
07/10/2019:08:00:00 PM
07/23/2019:08:00:00 PM
3/15/2021
8/15/2021
8/26/2021
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format is incorrect. Try:

```
df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"], format="%m/%d/%Y:%I:%M:%S %p")
```

You should be using `%I` to specify a 12-hour format and `%p` for AM/PM.
Separately, just use `pd.to_datetime` instead of importing `datetime` and using `apply`.

###### Example:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime('07/10/2019:08:00:00 PM', format="%m/%d/%Y:%I:%M:%S %p")
Timestamp('2019-07-10 20:00:00')
```

###### Edit:

To handle multiple formats, you can use `pd.to_datetime` with `fillna`:

```
df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"], format="%m/%d/%Y:%I:%M:%S %p", errors="coerce").fillna(pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"], format="%m/%d/%Y", errors="coerce"))
```

Comment: In my date column, some values are of the format '07/10/2019:08:00:00 PM' and some are just '07/10/2019'. How do I change all values of this column to datetime format without altering any values

Comment: Wrap it around another `pd.to_datetime`. See the edit

Comment: When I ran the original code (not the edit) it says "unconverted data remains: :08:00:00 PM"

Comment: You obviously have many different datetime formats in one column. "08:00:00 PM" doesn't fit either of the formats you mentioned in your first comment.

Comment: I just checked my excel file, those two are the only formats in the column

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a sample of `df["DATE"]`?